# The sphere with a differentiable atlas consisting of one chart?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, spheres

Maybe this is quite elementary, but how can I prove that the sphere $S^{n}$ cannot have a differentiable atlas consisting of only one chart?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By contradiction it follows that $\mathbb{S}^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ for a given $k$. If $k>0$, $\mathbb{R}^k$ is not compact while the $n$-sphere is, hence $k=0$. However, $\{0\}$ is discrete while $\mathbb{S}^n$ is not.